# Maxsub array using divide and conquer

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I am having trouble implementing max sub array problem using divide and conquer.

Lets say I have an array  [3,6,-1,2] and I want to find the max sum of this array in contiguous order. We can look at this and see that the sum is 10 from [0,3].

I tried implementing the pseudo code from my book but the answer is not correct.

```
// return (max-left, max-right, max sum left + right)
public static int[] maxcross(int[] array, int low, int mid, int high) {
    int leftSum = -10000000;
    int rightSum = -10000000;
    int sum = 0;
    int maxLeft=0;
    int maxRight=0;
    for(int i=mid;i<mid-low;i--){
        sum = sum + array[i];
        if(leftSum < sum){
            leftSum = sum;
            maxLeft = i;
        }
    }
    sum=0;
    for(int i=mid+1;i<high;i++){
        sum = sum + array[i];
        if(rightSum < sum){
            rightSum = sum;
            maxRight = i;
        }
    }
    int cross[] = {maxLeft,maxRight,leftSum+rightSum};
    return cross;
}

public static int[] maxsub(int array[], int low, int high){
    int[] maxSubLeft = new int[3];
    int[] maxSubRight = new int[3];
    int[] maxSub = new int[3];
    int[] maxSubCross = new int[3];
    int mid;
    if (high==low){
        maxSub[0] = low;
        maxSub[1] = high;
        maxSub[2] = array[low];
        return maxSub;
    }
    else{
        mid = (int) Math.floor((low+high)/2);
        maxSubLeft = maxsub(array,low,mid);
        maxSubRight = maxsub(array,mid+1,high);
        maxSubCross = maxcross(array,low,mid,high);

        if(maxSubLeft[2] >= maxSubRight[2] && maxSubLeft[2] >= maxSubCross[2])
            return maxSubLeft;
        else if(maxSubRight[2] >= maxSubLeft[2] && maxSubRight[2] >= maxSubCross[2])
            return maxSubRight;
        else
            return maxSubCross;
    }
}
```

I am getting this as the output

1

1

6

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recursive initial output is wrong in maxsub(...), `return 0` when `high=low` and `array[low]` < 0;

```
public static int[] maxsub(int array[], int low, int high){
    int[] maxSubLeft = new int[3];
    int[] maxSubRight = new int[3];
    int[] maxSub = new int[3];
    int[] maxSubCross = new int[3];
    int mid;
    if (high==low){
        maxSub[0] = low;
        maxSub[1] = high;
        maxSub[2] = array[low];
        return maxSub; // if (array[low] < 0) return 0;
    }
    else{
        mid = (int) Math.floor((low+high)/2);
        maxSubLeft = maxsub(array,low,mid);
        maxSubRight = maxsub(array,mid+1,high);
        maxSubCross = maxcross(array,low,mid,high);

        if(maxSubLeft[2] >= maxSubRight[2] && maxSubLeft[2] >= maxSubCross[2])
            return maxSubLeft;
        else if(maxSubRight[2] >= maxSubLeft[2] && maxSubRight[2] >= maxSubCross[2])
            return maxSubRight;
        else
            return maxSubCross;
    }
}
```

By the way, your recursive algorithm is O(NlnN), a more effective and easy to implement algorithm is O(N), which applies the dynamic programming.

```
public static int maxSum(int array[], int low, int high) {
   int maxsum = 0, maxleftsum = 0;
   for (int i = low; i < high; i++) {
       maxsum = max(maxsum, array[i] + maxleftSum);
       maxleftSum = max(0, maxleftSum+array[i]);
   }
   return maxsum; // return the index if necessary. 
}
```